# How to create the blConnection

Tags: c#, sql

how to create the blConnection (connection to the database)

Comment: What database? You need to give us some more context here! Read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand what it takes to make a question **good** on SO and give it a chance to be answered!

Comment: blConnection?? did you search ? did you visit www.ConnectionStrings.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will assign DB Connection path to a variable

```
public class blConnection
{
    private string constr = "Data Source=.\\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;Integrated Security=True";

    public string getConstr()   
    {
        return constr;
    }
}
```

Then you can reuse it in BL classes

```
public class blCustomerInformation
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter ada;

    blConnection myConn = new blConnection();

    public blCustomerInformation()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(myConn.getConstr());
        conn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ada.SelectCommand = cmd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway when u ask questions here, please give a more description.
it will helpful us to give you a better answer :)